# configparser module error and module exist conda virtualenv

Tags: python, tensorflow, virtualenv, conda

hello guys i have this error 
ImportError: No module named configparser

im using pycharm with conda virtualenv python 3.6 and configparser module exist but it seems its not callable

Comment: Where have you installed the configparser module? Are you sure you installed it in your env?

Comment: Have you tried other imports, such as math, json, unittest? Have you checked your PYTHONPATH, or sys.path?

Comment: Make sure you've set up the interpreter in PyCharm correctly. Settings -> Project Interpreter, and ensure that you're using the correct python version (you should be pointing at a /env/env_name/python.exe if using a conda environment).

Comment: guys when i activate the env from termianl then i import configparser then it exists but pycharm didnt find it i dont know why